# Mesh displaces when parenting to armature

Tags: armature

I´m trying to parent a cloth to an armature with automatic weights, but the cloth mesh offsets vertically when I do the parenting. The armature works correctly and the cloth deforms as it should, but it´s displaced vertically. I´ve already tried to reset/apply all transforms, and the result is the same.

Where could be the problem? The character and armature comes from Character Creator 3, I don´t know if the issue could be related to the armature.

[image: The cloth mesh before and after parenting]

Comment: maybe deparent the cloth before parenting?

Comment: I´ve already tried it. No effect.

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here it goes.

https://pasteall.org/blend/14715884acdf43b7b64c447160146048

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues.  You have unapplied transforms on the armature object, and your armature is not in rest pose.  Your clothing is built around the posed model.

Basically, you're using a bunch of different techniques to place things-- object transforms, edit mode changes, bone posing-- when you should just be using one.  Each of these techniques works kind of differently from the others.

Start by unparenting all objects (alt-p -> clear and keep transforms).  Next, find the armature modifier on your body and apply it from its drop-down menu.  Repeat for the eye object, the eye occlusion object, the teeth, tongue, and conjunctiva objects.

Now, select your armature and enter pose mode.  Select all bones and ctrl a (apply) -> apply pose as rest pose.

Return to object mode.  Select all objects and apply rotation and scale (ctrl a -> apply rotation & scale).  Parent objects to the armature as desired.  You will have to reparent objects that were parented before (but you don't have to redo your weights if you don't want, just parent with armature deform or empty groups.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the whole problem but it comes from the fact that the scale of the armature is not 1 and it seems to create a gap between the bone positions in *Edit* mode and *Pose* mode. So, to fix that:

In *Edit* mode, select the head of the bone called Pelvis (or the head of Hip), put the 3D cursor to selected, switch to *Pose* mode, select both Pelvis and Hip, and put the selection to cursor. Then back to *Object* mode, apply the scale, also apply the scale of the body. Parent the cloth.

Also I'm not completely sure about the cloth modifier stack order but it's another question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my eyelids and was caused by a lattice, because my *eyelids were parented to this lattice* and when I tried to parent my eyelids to the armature they changed the parenting making this weird displacement, working well but with an offset. So the **solution** was to first *clear de lattice parent of the eyelids, making sure it stays in the same position after disparenting, then parenting to the armature.* Hope this help anyone.